# Realization of representation of a finite group over smaller ring

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $\rho:G\rightarrow {\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$.

It is known that $\rho$ is equivalent to a representation $\rho':G\rightarrow {\rm GL}_n(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$.

**Q.** Is $\rho$ always equivalent to a representation $\rho'':G\rightarrow {\rm GL}_n(\mathcal{O})$? [$\mathcal{O}=$ ring of integers in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.]

---

**Edit:** The question has already been apeared on mathoverflow [(see this)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/847/is-any-representation-of-a-finite-group-defined-over-the-algebraic-integers): but two remarks:

- Question appeared in 2009; and latest answer to it was by Robinson in 2011.
- Robinson mentions ***it is still open whether every irreducible representation can be realized over $Z[\omega]$***; but here Robinson mentions open problem for very smaller ring, than the whole ring $\mathcal O$, which raises question whether it is still open for $\mathcal{O}$ instead of $Z[\omega]$?

Comment: Characters are always algebraic integer valued. Therefore, yes you are right.

Comment: @Levent It is not completely clear to me how the statement follows from that on the characters. Sums of non-integers can still be integers in general.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes you are right. I might me wrong.

Comment: It appears to me that representation matrices can usually be made to have non-algebraic integer coefficients by applying a weird conjugation. So the question is not whether they _have to_ have algebraic integer coefficients, but whether they _can be chosen_ to have such coefficients. I think characters can be used to project to a specific component in the regular representation of the group, and I would expect the result to only have algebraic integer coefficients, but I admit some details are needed.

Comment: of course; I am asking *is $\rho$* ***equivalent*** to a representation $\rho''$ over $\mathcal{O}$?